# Query Firebase Realtime Database to find children which has a given key in it's data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have around 2 million users at a branch in a database. Each user may contain a property called `activeSessionId` which tells me if this user has ever started a web session to my app. There is also an array called sessions that contains data for all the web sessions this user has ever started. I have found some bugs in the code which may cause the users who have started a web session to the app to have some invalid data causing the mobile app to become unresponsive. I want to traverse all the users who have started a web session and fix that data.

If I traverse over all the users, the code fails with firebase complaining about too much data to read. So, I am trying to think of a query that could just give me the users that have an `activeSessionId` defined and I just traverse over those. But I can't think of any such query. The `equalTo` method doesn't allow for an `undefined` value for a property.

Below is what a user looks like in firebase that has an `activeSessionId`.

```js
Top level
  userInfos: {
    "-NL1sdfee29E7bQ53_rJTW": {
      "activeSessionId": "-NL1aKF29E7bQ53_rJTW",
      "alarmsCount": {
        "ownAlarms": {
          "Personal": {
            "edit": 1244,
            "new": 436
          }
        }
      },
      "contactsLastUpdatedAt": 1675435956007,
      "deviceLocale": "en-US",
      "deviceOs": "android",
      "joinDate": 1649084020051,
      "lastActiveAt": 1675435953311,
      "maxAllowedAlarms": 5,
      "rateTheApp": {
        "done": true,
        "lastAsked": 1675435981073
      },
      "release": "7.4.3",
      "sessions": {
        "-NL1aKF29E7bQ53_rJTW": {
          "browser": "Chrome",
          "id": "-NL1aKF29E7bQ53_rJTW",
          "lastActive": "10 Jan 2023, 11:22 AM",
          "platform": "Windows"
        }
      },
      "timezone": "America/Denver",
      "timezoneOffset": 420,
      "totalNumberOfContacts": 282
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to create such a query for Firebase Realtime Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Realtime Database, there is no way you can query a node based on a field that doesn't exist. So if you want to perform a query that returns the users that have the `activeSessionId` field set to a particular value and the users that don't have the `activeSessionId` field at all, that isn't possible.

A possible workaround would be to denormalize the data and create a node that contains **only** the users that have already set the `activeSessionId` field or don't have the `activeSessionId` field at all.

However, if you consider at some point in time using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), then please note that you can achieve something similar using [whereIn()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) in a query that looks like this:

```
db.collection("products").whereIn("activeSessionId", Arrays.asList("someId", "defaultId"))
```

This means that you have to set a default value to all users who don't have set a specific ID.

Also, in the case of Firestore, a query like this:

```
db.collection("products").whereIn("activeSessionId", Arrays.asList("someId", null));
```

Won't work. Besides that, you cannot also query for non-existing fields. There is no "undefined" value for Firestore fields. Here are the [supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). You can see that null is a supported data type but **not** undefined.

So we cannot query for fields that don't exist in Firestore. We can only search for fields that exist in the index, hence the presence of the `defaultId` in that array.

Comment: Hey Varun. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for the delay in responding. If I have the option of changing the data structure or the database, I would definitely maintain a separate list of users who have started a web session. A practice that I follow for many other things to make it easier to access data. I will definitely start doing that from now onwards. Good to know that Firestore also has some limitations w.r.t. this kind of query.

Trouble remains for how to edit the existing data. I really wish Firebase Realtime Database would allow me to traverse over all of my data if needed.